# in R how to write a matrix to csv, keeping row names for real row but not the column name row

Tags: r

for example my matrix looks like this:

> ```
>      in out
> ```
>
> 08:00     NA  NA
>
> 14:30     NA  NA
>
> 15:00     NA  NA

if I do this:

```
write.csv(updates_to_save, file="foo.csv", quote=FALSE)
```

the csv file will look like:

> ,in,out
>
> 08:00,NA,NA
>
> 14:30,NA,NA
>
> 15:00,NA,NA

How do I get rid of the "," in the first line? or alternatively how can I add a value there to indicate that's the column for row names?

Comment: Alternately, if you want to keep the times, you could convert your matrix into a data frame and add a column for the times, calling it whatever you want. Then you would output the data frame with row.names=FALSE.

Comment: You can use unname() function to get rid of the names.

Comment: I don't want to get rid of the row names, just the first empty one. I'll try converting to data frame then.

Comment: yeah, I mostly do `write.csv(data.frame(ID=row.names(updates_to_save),updates_to_save), "foo.csv", row.names=FALSE)`